# Test if a certain div is present in another

Tags: jquery

This might be easy but i get a problem,

How to test if the div comWF if present at least one time in comW ?

eg :

```
<div class="comW">
   <div class="comWF"></div>
</div>
```

if i make :

```
if($(".comWF").length>=1)) doSomething;
```

It test on the wall body not especially in each comW.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.comW').each(function(){
 var hasElem = $('.comWF', this).length;
 if( hasElem ){
    // do something
 }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
if($('.comW .comWF').length > 0)
{
   //comWF is present in comW
}
```

Update on request of OP, for all the html section satisfying the criteria.

```
$('.comW .comWF').each(function(){

    var comWFobj = $(this);
    var comWobj = $(this).closest('.comW');

    alert(comWFobj.attr('class'));
    alert(comWobj.attr('class'));

});
```

Comment: Thanks but how to do that with each ?

Comment: g :    
    $(".comW").each(function(){
       if($(this)+" .comWF").length>0){
           
       }
    });

Comment: This will check all the elements in the document. I have updated my answer tell me if you need more...

Comment: @user1475195: Use `if ($(this).find(".comWF").length) { ... }` in your loop.

Comment: each give in answer act as loop, it will give you all the element have class comWF, I have updated my answer again

Answer (score 3):

```
var present = $('.comW .comWF').length > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery provides a dedicated static method for this task - [`$.contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/):

```
if ( $.contains( divW, divWF ) ) {
    // do your thing
}
```

where `divW`, and `divWF` are DOM references to those DIVs.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8SadD/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
if ($('.comW').find('.comWF').length > 0){
// Put your code here
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ovilip/6/edit)*

```
if($('.comW').find('.comWF').length){
   // found!
}
```

or better:

```
$('.comW').each(function(){
  var $myChild = $(this).find('.comWF');
  if($myChild.length){
     // DO SOMETHING
  }
});
```